# How to assign a signal to a QMenu instead of QAction in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I would like to have a menu item without children. I have a QMenubar, and in this menubar there is a QMenu. To use it as a menu, I have to put QActions in it, and they will appear if I click on the QMenu. How is it possible, to have only the menu, without any QActions, to do an action just as if it were a QAction?

A workaround would be to have a toolbox and disguise it as a menu, but it raises several problems:

- It's not the cleanest solution
- I have to manually care about highlighting it on mouse hover, and it will not be platform- and user setting independent.
- I can't use it together in a menubar with normal menus with children.

Comment: Having a menu without `QAction`s seems meaningless to me. However, if you want to trigger only one slot for several `QAction`s, you can use QActionGroup: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qactiongroup.html

Comment: What I really want can be described as having only one QAction, but it should not be in a dropdown menulist, but it should be the top-level item in the menu. If I add a single QAction, there will be a menu list with a single item when I click on the menu.

Comment: So you want the top level menu item to work as a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want a menu bar that triggers actions without opening sub-menus?

Try to directly add QActions to the menubar, instead of having a QMenu inbetween:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *wnd = new QMainWindow;
    QMenuBar *m = new QMenuBar;
    QAction *a = new QAction("DoIt");

    QObject::connect(a, &QAction::triggered, [wnd](){
        QMessageBox::information(wnd, "DoIt", "DoIt");
    });

    m->addAction(a);
    wnd->setMenuBar(m);
    wnd->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Alternatively, you could subclass the QMenu and handle the mousePressEvent method to emit a signal

Comment: Thanks, I added the QAction directly to the menubar. It's a pity Qt Creator does not allow it in the ui editor, and all the signals and slots have to be written manually.

Comment: I tried directly adding a QAction to the menubar, but it creates a menu with an "Activate" action which does nothing...

Comment: I don't do C, but the equivalent PyQt code just creates a menu with an "Activate" button which does nothing:

```from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
wnd = QtGui.QMainWindow()
m = QtGui.QMenuBar()
a = QtGui.QAction("DoIt", m)
a.triggered.connect(lambda wnd: QtGui.QMessageBox.information(wnd, "DoIt", "DoIt"))
m.addAction(a)
wnd.setMenuBar(m)
wnd.show()
app.exec_()```

Comment: @Krenair I don't know Python. You should ask a separate question.